# Menu button remove label padding with CSS

Tags: menu, label, padding

I am setting a label to a menu button what looks like this:

[image: menubutton with label]

Now I would like to remove the padding so the label fills the complete menu button.

The CSS I am applying now to the menu button removes its drop down arrow:

```
.menu-button_wo_arrow > .arrow-button, .menu-button > .arrow-button > .arrow {
-fx-padding: 0;
```

}

But I am struggling to find a solution how to set the padding for the label to 0. I would need to keep the drop down arrow removed and get rid of the padding.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it:

```
.menu-button >.label {
    -fx-padding: 0;   
}
```